# Oracle insert hangs on simple statement

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, create-table

I am using toad9.5 and create a table successfully with this statement:

```
create table AC11555.testlake2oracle4 (MI_NAME NVARCHAR2(255), FIELD_TYPE NVARCHAR2(255), 
RESPONSE_FIELD_NAME NVARCHAR2(255), ORIGINAL_NAME NVARCHAR2(255), TSTNG_THS_LNG_CLMNTHTWLDBRKRCL INT,
 JKJKJKJKJKJKATWOULDBREAKORACLE INT, JKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKATWOULDBREAK FLOAT, BOOLTEST INT )
```

but then it hangs forever when trying to insert a simple statement:

```
insert into AC11555.TESTLAKE2ORACLE4 (
MI_NAME , FIELD_TYPE , RESPONSE_FIELD_NAME , 
ORIGINAL_NAME , TSTNG_THS_LNG_CLMNTHTWLDBRKRCL , JKJKJKJKJKJKATWOULDBREAKORACLE , 
JKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKATWOULDBREAK , BOOLTEST 
) 
values ('1', '1', '1', '1', 1, 1, 1.1234, 1)
```

I can select from it (it's obviously empty) and I can delete it no issues.  I've hit commit, and rollback countless times and not sure why this is happening.

Comment: works for me.  You sure you don't have some other session/lock on the table?

Comment: how could I check, or end all of them?  Is there a command for that?

Comment: Also I appreciate the feedback. I don't have anyone else to ask to test to see if it was me or not.  That alone is helping me to debug this.